# Nginx ingress controller - Helm chart Failed to list *v1 VirtualServerRoute

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I’m trying to update my nginx ingress controller helm chart.

I’m getting an error “cannot list virtualserverroutes.k8s.nginx.org at cluster scope”.

Is there a way to disable custom resources in the Helm deployment.yaml/daemonset.yaml?
I’ve seen similar issues on git and this seems to fix it, but I don’t believe the authors of the posts are using helm to deploy nginx ingress?

Really confused, any help would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the list/watch operations on virtualserver and virtualserverroutes - set the --enable-custom-resources flag to false in your deployment/daemonset manifest.

```html
--enable-custom-resources
Enables custom resources (default true)
```

This should get it fixed.

Comment: https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/v1.12.4/deployments/helm-chart/templates/controller-deployment.yaml this is what the yaml looks like. Would it just be —enable-custom-resources = false??